# GTA Vice City hangs on my PSP

Tags: psp, grand-theft-auto-vice-city-stories

*GTA: Vice City* is making my PSP hang. It was working fine until I cleaned the CD with a spirit solution. Now, whenever I play the game, my PSP hangs. What should I do? This happens only with this particular CD.

Comment: It MIGHT (maybe) be dead, GG.

Answer (score -2):

Check your save data on the memory stick.